# Optimize dynamic SQL stored procedure by reducing the unique query plans generated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

For the below query, SQL Server is creating a unique query plan depending on the parameter which is passed, Is there any way to optimize the below query to reduce the number of query plans and optimize the query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Foo_search]
    @ItemID INT, 
    @LastName VARCHAR(50), 
    @MiddleName VARCHAR(40), 
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(max) 

    SELECT @Sql = N 'Select ID, FirstName, FamilyName, MiddleName, MaidenName, Email,  From Employees Where DeletedOn Is Null ' + 
        CASE WHEN @LastName IS NULL OR @LastName = '' THEN '' ELSE ' And FamilyName=''' + @LastName + ''' ' END + 
        CASE WHEN @MiddleName IS NULL OR @MiddleName = '' THEN '' ELSE ' And MiddleName=''' + @MiddleName + ''' ' END + 
        CASE WHEN @FirstName IS NULL OR @FirstName = '' THEN '' ELSE ' And FirstName=''' + @FirstName + ''' ' END + 
        CASE WHEN @ItemID IS NOT NULL AND @ItemID > 0 THEN ' And ItemID=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @ItemID) + ' ' ELSE ' ' END 

    EXEC Sp_executesql @sql 
END
```

Comment: But you actually want multiple query plans, that means you are getting an optimal query based on the parameters passed in? If you make it a generic query you'll have one query plan and poor performance.

Comment: Why do you want to _reduce_ the number of query plans, and what would that optimize exactly? The whole point of using dynamic SQL for this is so that you get a plan optimized for each combination of parameters, rather than a single plan that can't possibly be optimized for all combinations. See [kitchen sink](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).

Comment: @DaleK The query is taking much of CPU when creating different query plans, ideally in my case I feel a generic query would be of better performance. I have query parameterization in my mind to implement, but looking for any other possible solutions

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have already seen that solution, I'm looking if there's a better solution than that.

Comment: Can you show what evidence you've collected that suggests that _compilation of these plans_ is what is driving the CPU usage you think is your problem? A "better solution" certainly isn't to reduce the number of plans that are possible, unless part of the solution is reducing the users' ability to use optional parameters in the first place.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The query I have posted as the question is not the same query being used, instead there are many other statements in the original query. I have checked the top resource-consuming queries in the query store and I could find that queries related to this stored procedure has popped up in my findings.

Comment: But that doesn't mean that _multiple plans are the problem_ or that _having just one plan for all possible parameters will be any better_. It could just be that this is the table that has the worst indexing strategy and will be a top consumer no matter how you formulate the queries against it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243508/discussion-between-vamsi-simhadri-and-aaron-bertrand).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a way you can improve it, use the parameters correctly, rather than using string concatenation. Your method will generate a different query plan for every different combination of **values** of parameter, rather than just every different combination of parameters, which will generate orders of magnitude more query plans.

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) = N'
Select ID, FirstName, FamilyName, MiddleName, MaidenName, Email
From Employees
Where DeletedOn Is Null
'
    + CASE WHEN @LastName <> '' THEN ' And FamilyName = @LastName' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN @MiddleName <> '' THEN ' And MiddleName = @MiddleName' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN @FirstName <> '' THEN ' And FirstName = @FirstName' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN @ItemID > 0 THEN ' And ItemID = @ItemID' ELSE '' END;

EXEC sp_executesql
  @Sql,
  N'@LastName varchar(50), @MiddleName varchar(40), @FirstName varchar(50)',
  @LastName = @LastName,
  @MiddleName = @MiddleName,
  @FirstName = @FirstName;
```

And as Aaron Bertrand points out, this also fixes the issue where any parameter value containing a single quote (`'`) will fail.

Beyond this however, as Aaron also mentions, the performance is most likely down to other issues such as indexing.

Comment: This is a good point, as the OP clearly didn't try `@LastName = 'O''Toole'`. But still, "too many plans."

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have tried the above solution apparently, it's actually taking more time than the query provided in the question. Any other things I'm missing checking out?

Comment: You don't need to check for null, because if you check for `<> ''` then it also excludes nulls

Comment: Recommend using this approach even if it is slower as it protects you from SQL Injection attacks. Performance < Security. As for performance, it should be the same or probably better at scale due to execution plan reuse. @VamsiSimhadri how did you test performance? Did you run this proc at scale with many different parameter combos and many executions? Also I recommend using logical reads (and maybe cpu worker time) as your KPI. Execution time is generally too variable, SSMS, network, and other activity on the server can influence execution time very easily

Comment: @Stephan I ended up using the above solution after doing tests from my end

Comment: its useful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're blaming the right thing, but if you really think that multiple plans are causing your CPU spikes, it's easy to change this back to a single plan strategy:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Foo_search
    @ItemID INT, 
    @LastName VARCHAR(50), 
    @MiddleName VARCHAR(40), 
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50) 
AS 
BEGIN 
  Select ID, FirstName, FamilyName, MiddleName, MaidenName, Email
  From dbo.Employees 
  Where DeletedOn Is Null
    AND (FamilyName = @LastName OR @LastName IS NULL)
    AND (MiddleName = @MiddleName OR @MiddleName IS NULL)
    AND (FirstName = @FirstName OR @FirstName IS NULL)
    AND (ItemID = @ItemID OR @ItemID IS NULL);
END
```

Let us know how that works out for you; I'm curious what index you're going to implement to make that perform well for all possible parameter combinations.

Comment: Would this not benefit from a `RECOMPILE` in the `OPTION` clause? Otherwise whatever the first plan that cached is could be useless for the next run. Of course that would mean the query uses a different plan for the different `NULL`able parameters, but it doesn't store them... Just feel like this could end of with even worse performance depending on the single cached plan.

Comment: @Larnu I specifically and intentionally left out RECOMPILE because the OP thinks their problem is high CPU due to too much compilation. The article they’ve seen and rejected does go through that.

Comment: Hadn't noticed you'd commented about it in the question comments.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  I have tried the above solution and the kitchen sink solution you provided apparently, it's actually taking more time than the query provided in the question. Any other ways to optimize the query? Or Am I missing something?

Comment: @Vamsi I thought I was pretty clear that I did _not_ expect this answer to work better than what you already had, because more plans are better. If the tailored queries are slow then as I already suggested I still believe it is something to do with the indexes and not some enormous overhead from compilation. You started with complaining about CPU spikes and now the queries are slow. Is it one or the other or both? Can you share an actual execution plan from an instance of a query that was slow and/or you claim caused higher CPU?

Comment: @Vamsi Also I’m not sure I understand how the kitchen sink could be slower than what you have in the question, they’re essentially the same thing. But the article talks about option (recompile) (and Larnu’s comment mentioned it too) - I left it out here on purpose because you were complaining about compilation CPU spikes, but it can be a very important part of the strategy even when you’re building multiple plans, because it helps deal also with value skew.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have added the recompile too, the query in the question is taking less time than the query in the "sink" article even though they are the same. I'm still investigating this issue in more depth and I will post if I obtain any kind of solution. The query is only causing CPU spikes and there is no performance issue with the query.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I ended up using the solution provided by Dale K

Comment: @VamsiSimhadri Cool. That looks a lot like the kitchen sink and I think you have either forgotten about any performance issues or have realized that they weren't coming from where you thought they were. Also cool. I posted this answer not because I thought it would be faster than what you have, but actually to demonstrate that it is going to be worse. Perhaps I should have made that clearer in the post.